# Electron.js+Socket.io dando error

Tags: node.js, electron

Alguem sabe resolver esse erro "polling.js:298 GET http://file/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OZpxKwH net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Document

```
<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io()

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Conectado ao servidor Socket.IO')
  })

  socket.on('atualizarEstado', estadoDoJogo => {
    // Manipular os dados atualizados do jogo recebidos do servidor
    // ...
  })
</script>
<script src="menu.js"></script>
<script src="game.js"></script>
<script src="player1.js"></script>
<script src="player2.js"></script>
```

```

Meu server.js

```javascript
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const { Server } = require('socket.io')
const io = new Server(server)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.use(
  '/socket.io',
  express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist')
)

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('Novo jogador conectado: ' + socket.id)

  // Evento para receber dados do jogador
  socket.on('dadosJogador', dados => {
    // Lógica para processar os dados recebidos do jogador
    // e atualizar o estado do jogo
    // ...

    // Evento para enviar dados atualizados para todos os jogadores
    io.emit('atualizarEstado', estadoDoJogo)
  })

  // Resto do código do servidor Socket.IO
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Servidor Socket.IO rodando na porta 3000.')
})
```

meu index.js

```javascript
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron')

const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000')

require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
  electron: require(`${__dirname}/node_modules/electron`)
})

let janelaPrincipal

app.on('ready', () => {
  janelaPrincipal = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 1000,
    transparent: true,
    //frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  janelaPrincipal.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

  socket.on('atualizarEstado', estadoDoJogo => {})

  function enviarDadosJogador(dados) {
    socket.emit('dadosJogador', dados)
  }
})

/*const templateMenu = [
  {
    label: 'Console'
  }
]

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(templateMenu)
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)*/
```

Meu package.json

```json
{
  "name": "battlemath",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^25.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-reload": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here and belong on [so]. You should delete this question and post there.

Comment: And post there in English.

Comment: A guy on stackflow told me to post the question here because my error wasn't programming @Mokubai

Comment: Whoever told you to ask here is wrong. If the problem is in some interaction of your code then it is off topic here.

Comment: @MacacoBranco, and the guy there also told you that it seems that a typing error (since `http://file/` is not a correct domain. Nowhere in the pasted code shows why it tries to access the URL http://file/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OZpxKwH but in this URL the domain is obviously incorrect.)